# How to add confirmation check for a button which is calling a remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a situation in primefaces, where I have a button which on click calls a remote command through java script as a callback, this remote command is responsible to perform save action. I want to add confirmation to the Save button based on some controller value. So the expected output is on click if that value is true I want to show the confirmation dialog else I just want to do the normal save.

I am really new to primefaces. Any help would be highly appreciated.

`<p:remoteCommand name="save" actionListener="#{controller.save()}" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>`

`<p:button value="Save" styleClass="btn-primary btn-save" onclick="PF('statusDialog').show(); Modeler.saveBpmnToForm(save)" />`

Comment: Did you try to use the classic confirm panel of Primefaces? http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml?jfwid=73b61
If that can help you, you should disable it and enable it evaluating your boolean condition

Comment: Hii @SimoneLungarella, the classic confirm dosent seem to work for me, do we have any other approach..?

Comment: I show another approach as a Answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you trigger the `remote command` you could redirect the action to show the actual confirm dialog, then from there you can associate the action with the "confirm" button. The following logic is meant to show the dialog only if your boolean variable is `true`, otherwise you perform the `save` action without showing any dialog.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="save" actionListener="#{controller.status ? 
controller.showDialog : controller.save}" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>
```

Whenever this remoteCommand is triggered you'll show the following dialog using the bean:

```
<p:dialog id="confirmDialog" >
    <p:button value="Confirm" styleClass="btn-primary btn-save" 
    onclick="PF('statusDialog').show()" action="#{controller.save}"/>
    
    <p:button value="Cancel" styleClass="btn-primary btn-cancel" 
    onclick="PF('confirmDialog').hide()"/>
</p:dialog>
```

The "confirm" button will perform the actual logic, the "cancel" should only close the dialog but this is up to you.